# Byte Data HexaDecimal Enoded & Decode

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, hex

##### INTRO

I'm trying to decode hexadecimal data but there seems to be an error, as in the **results** that show **strange data**.

Is this true?

because if you look at the **Hex Editor** it looks **different**

##### GOAL

Goal is to be able to decode and re-encode correctly

##### LIBRARY

[ByteBuffer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytebuffer)

##### DECODE

```js
        const encoded = '646563376466306366356337666138333036626432383062646634666161393794000000840000008E06EA623666613634613632376334616237613300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000E6969800312E383500000000C80200000000000028151517313635663738333737353635383163310000000000000000000000000000000002000000366B17186566373463346331393162343939663661653865373863643038366532393763'

        let result = []

        const decode = ByteBufferJS.fromHex(encoded, ByteBufferJS.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    
        result.push(decode.readString(32)) // signature
        result.push(decode.readLong().toInt())
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // timestamp
        result.push(decode.readString(16)) // mac
        result.push(decode.readString(24)) // unknown
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // platform
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // agent_id
        result.push(decode.readString(4)) // version
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // unknown
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // unknown
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // unknown
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // user_id
        result.push(decode.readString(16)) // token
        result.push(decode.readString(16)) // mac
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // unknown
        result.push(decode.readInt()) // user_destination
        result.push(decode.readString(32)) // unknown
    
        console.log(result)
```

##### RESULT

```js
[
  'dec7df0cf5c7fa8306bd280bdf4faa97',
  148,
  1659504270,
  '6fa64a627c4ab7a3',
  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
  1,
  10000102,
  '1.85',
  0,
  712,
  0,
  387257640,
  '165f7837756581c1',
  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
  2,
  404187958,
  'ef74c4c191b499f6ae8e78cd086e297c'
]
```

#### HEX EDITOR

[Hex Editor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPyVo.png)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: a way to encode in the return result so that the result is the same in the encoded variable

Comment: I don't understand, they looks identical for me, I checked many times, can you highlight the difference so we can help ?

Comment: @AhmedLazhar

this is a sample sample re-encoding but the result is not the same

https://pastebin.com/bFpSk2m2

Comment: What is it you're ultimately trying to do with this encode/decode..? It's the same raw data, just being represented in different ways.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing, I think I can overwrite the byte offset to change the user_id or signature

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

```
result.push(decode.readString(32)) // signature
```

Gives:

```
[
  'dec7df0cf5c7fa8306bd280bdf4faa97',
  // ...
]
```

Which is the first 32 characters of the ASCII representation of that hexadecimal encoded data.

Looking at the API of the library you're using, namely - https://github.com/protobufjs/bytebuffer.js/wiki/API#bytebufferreadstringlength-metrics-offset - I can see that the 32 refers to number of characters to draw from the buffer, which is exactly what it's done, and it's correct.

There's no issue here...

Comment: could you check this ? i'm trying to re-encode but result is wrong

https://pastebin.com/bFpSk2m2

Comment: I think it'd be better if you created a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue, and update the question.